# How to declare a global string pointer without using llvm::IRBuilder

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Here is the code that print `hello world` of LLVM IR:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    llvm::LLVMContext &Context = llvm::getGlobalContext();
    llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(Context);
    llvm::Module *pModule = new llvm::Module("hello world", Context);
    llvm::FunctionType *funcType = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getInt32Ty(), false);
    llvm::Function *mainFunc = llvm::Function::Create(funcType, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", pModule);
    llvm::BasicBlock *pEntryBB  = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(Context, "EntryPoint", mainFunc);
    builder.SetInsertPoint(pEntryBB);
    llvm::Value *pHelloWorldStr = builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr("hello world!\n");
    std::vector<llvm::Type *> PrintfProtoArgs;
    PrintfProtoArgs.push_back(builder.getInt8Ty()->getPointerTo());
    llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Type*> argsRef(PrintfProtoArgs);
    llvm::FunctionType *pPrintfType = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getInt32Ty(), argsRef, false);
    llvm::Constant *pPrintfFunc = pModule->getOrInsertFunction("printf", pPrintfType);
    builder.CreateCall(pPrintfFunc, pHelloWorldStr);
    builder.CreateRetVoid();
    pModule->dump();

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying discarding `llvm::IRBuilder<>` and replacing it with some Module/Function/BasicBlock specified function:

`builder.CreateCall` -> `llvm::CallInst::llvm::CallInst::Create(pPrintfFunc, pHelloWorldStr, "callPrintf", pEntryBB)`

`builder.CreateRetVoid()` -> `llvm::ReturnInst::Create(Context, pConsIntZero, pEntryBB);`

`builder.getInt32Ty()` -> `llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(Context)`

Now problem is that I couldn't find an alternative for `CreateGlobalStringPtr`:

`llvm::Value *pHelloWorldStr = builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr("hello world!\n");`

So, how to declare a global string pointer without using the builder?

I suppose `llvm::IRBuilder` is not necessary in every case. Is there an easy way to find such alternative function?

Comment: You can look at the code for `IRBuilder` to see what it does.